# How to get a streaming output from a Llama 2 model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, llama

I am unable to parse the streaming output from a Llama model deployed on Sage Maker?
Can someone help me with this??

Tried to read Bytes array and parse it. However, the output is returned together instead of streaming line by line.